# Convert to date format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, date, format

I have the following date: **2010-04-19 18:31:27**. I would like to convert this date to the **dd/mm/yyyy** format.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can use a regular expression or some manual string fiddling, but I think I prefer:

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($str));
```

Comment: I find on a lot of our servers (operating on Australian time) I need to use: date("d/m/o", strtotime($str)); -> i.e 'o' for the year.

Comment: Hi there!

I have already tried your solution but does not seems to work. Like I asked on my post, I just need the date in the dd/mm/yyyy format without the time component.

Thanks for the help, 
Best regards!

Comment: Which part doesn't work? `strtotime("2010-04-19 18:31:27");` returns the seconds since the epoch, `1271716287` (for my TZ). `date()` takes a format string and an epoch int; the format string tells it what to return, and "d/m/Y" is days as a zero-padded int, months as a zero-padded int, and year as four digits. Since no time parameters are included in the format string (e.g. "d/m/Y h:i:s"), they won't be returned

Comment: Hi there!

I was commiting an error with the application of the suggested solution. It worked just fine! To all others, thanks for the responses.

Thanks again for the response!
Best regards

Comment: And current date `date("d/m/Y");`

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php
$test1='2010-04-19 18:31:27';
echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($test1));
?>
```

try this

Answer (score 3):

If your date is in the format of a string use the explode function

```
    array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )
//In the case of your code

$length = strrpos($oldDate," ");
$newDate = explode( "-" , substr($oldDate,$length));
$output = $newDate[2]."/".$newDate[1]."/".$newDate[0];
```

Hope the above works now

Comment: This is far more complex of a solution than what is needed.

Comment: But useful for other possible cases.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the `DateTime` object if you want to go that way: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try
**$date=date('d/m/Y',strtotime($yourdatevariable))**

or else you want to convert to d-m-Y
Just Simply **Edit above d/m/Y with d-m-Y**

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```cs
$old_date = Date_create("2010-04-19 18:31:27");
$new_date = Date_format($old_date, "d/m/Y");
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$source    =    'your varible name';
$date    =     new DateTime($source);
$_REQUEST["date"]    =     $date->format('d-m-Y');

echo $_REQUEST["date"];
```

Comment: Please don't leave signatures under your post.

Comment: The question says convert to "dd/mm/yyyy". This solution seems to give the wrong format.