# How to convert "2011-02-14 16:14:57" into DD/MM/YYYY format in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have a task to display the date in DD/MM/YYYY format, But I Have date stored as "2011-02-14 16:14:57" format, hence how can i convert it to get the DD/MM/YYYY in PHP?

Comment: the basic answer will be check the manual!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Convert to date format dd/mm/yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671145/php-convert-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("2011-02-14 16:14:57"));
```

If you want more ways to do it, see PHP [datetime extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Comment: eh? I presume you meant `strtotime()` rather than `strftime()`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[Convert to date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671145/php-convert-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 0):

```
$n      =   "2011-02-14 16:14:57";
echo $time_output=date("d/m/Y",strtotime($n));
```