# WordPress custom fields expiry date

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have Wordpress custom field expiry date and i have saved it in format yy/dd/mm. But in admin panel i want it to display in format dd/mm/yy. So, how can I change the format in admin panel?

```
$expired_date = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($current_date. '+ '.$expire_after.'days'));
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'Date_MoveToFilledJobs',$expired_date, true);
```

My code is this for add meta but in admin panel I want it to display in format of d/m/Y.

Comment: Where you want to show this custom field? in Setting panel or Posts/Pages panel?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: in edit post admin panel

Comment: or else is there any other way that i can convert expire date in time stamp  post meta while executing wp query ?

Comment: Correct the Wordpress spelling!! It creates disrespect to the Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

somthing like this `date("d/m/Y", strtotime($str));`

from here 
[Convert to date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671145/convert-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)